# Latex Quiz to SCORM Quiz

Tags: latex, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I have 500 quizzes written in Latex.
Each quiz has this format:

```
\begin{question}
\subject{Geometria}
\topic{Geometria Analitica}
\difficulty{A}
\choice{Formula Matematica 1}
\choice{Formula Matematica 2}
\choice[!]{Formula Matematica 3}
\choice{Formula Matematica 4}
\choice{Formula Matematica 5}
\end{question}
```

I want to convert this quizzes into SCORM packages in order to upload them on Moodle and on SCORM Cloud (in order to use them on non SCORM compliant systems).
Is there a tool that do this work in an automatic way?
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Andrea

Comment: Hi! Please add your preamble to the question ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Comment: Could you provide an example of what a "SCORM package" look like (the expected output)?

Comment: One option is to create `HTML` file of a `SCORM` packages contains `SCO`s(all those quizzes). Then you can pack and create a `zip` file for `LMS`-which is Moodle on this occasion.